# What does MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer() return for JIT compiled method?

Tags: .net, jit

If the method is JIT compiled, does `MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer()` point to actual compiled code or to some intermediate stub/jump?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it can always be a stub.  Whether the jitter compiled the call or you use GetFunctionPointer().  Happens on a COM interop or interface method for example.  Whether GetFunctionPointer() forces the jitter to compile the method isn't so obvious from source, I can't find GetMultiCallableAddrOfCode().  The name says "no".  You can't reliably tell either because the address is usually the same.